# Проблема с запуском Винды

Tags: windows, запуск

Первый раз заморочку обнаружил вчера: после перезагрузки комп сам не вошел в единственную (кроме Гостя) учетку. Сегодня включил комп - то же самое: пока Интер не нажал, дальше не пошло. Что бы это могло быть? Вообще ничего не менял, систему не откатывал.

Comment: такое бывает как раз после включения гостя, а то что учётка одна, ещё автоматом автологин не включает. Включите автологин повторно, в интернете полно инструкций

Comment: Так я вообще никого не включал. Нашел, к примеру, здесь: http://esate.ru/article/windows-7/publikatsii_o_windows_7/avtomaticheskiy-vhod-v-sistemu-windows-7/ Это если у меня пароля нет, то мне в диалоговом окне "Автоматический вход в систему" в текстовые поля *Пароль* и *Подтверждение* вообще ничего не указывать?

Comment: Бывает иногда отключается автологин, по разным причинам. Попробуйте с пустым паролём, если не выйдет, такое бывает, придётся его задать и указать

Comment: Угу, ладно, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: Ночью перед отключением сделал, как рассказано в ссылке выше, сделал без пароля. Сейчас включил, немного погодя интернет отрубился, перезагрузил комп. В обоих случаях комп вошел сам. Еще раз спасибо.